# PHP to JavaScript Confirm Message Box Variable Undefined (but has value)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

First post on the forum, although frequent reader, need a solution for this:

php program populating html table rows:

```
echo "<td align='left' class='padded'><a href='#' onClick='confirmArrival(".$rowCont['id'].");'>Process</a></td>";
```

when user clicks to process item, JavaScript confirm message is displayed with the function:

```
            function confirmArrival(itemId)
            {
                
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to process this Item ?\n"+itemId))
                {
                    window.location='processscript_item1.php?itemId='+itemId;
                }
            }
```

I need to display the value of another php record, changed the onClick to send 2 args:

```
echo "<td align='left' class='padded'><a href='#' onClick='confirmArrival(".$rowCont['id'].",".$rowCont['second_item'].");'>Process</a></td>";
```

and changed the function:

```
function confirmArrival(itemId, second_item)
            {
                
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to process this Item ?\n"+second_item))
                {
                    window.location='processcript_item1.php?itemId='+itemId;
                }
            }
```

Getting UnCaught ReferenceError: (second_item variable value displayed here) is not defined

Message box is not displayed, but I can see the values being passed

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes

```
onClick='confirmArrival(\'".$rowCont['id']."\',\'".$rowCont['second_item']."\')
```

I suggest to delegate and use attributes

```
 <td align='left' class='padded'><a href='#' 
   class="confirm" 
   data-id='<?= $rowCont[' id ']?>' 
   data-second='<?= $rowCont[' second_item '] ?>'>Process</a></td>
```

like this

```js
document.getElementById('tableId').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('confirm')) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to process this Item ?\n" + tgt.dataset.second)) {
      tgt.href = 'processcript_item1.php?itemId=' + tgt.dataset.id;
      console.log("going to ", tgt.href)
    } else {
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align='left' class='padded'><a href='#' class="confirm" data-id='ID1' data-second='Second item 1'>Process</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align='left' class='padded'><a href='#' class="confirm" data-id='ID2' data-second='Second item 2'>Process</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you @mplungjan tried your first solution and getting Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence for onClick='confirmArrival(\'".$rowCont['id']."\',\'".$rowCont['second_item']."\')

Comment: it works appreciate your suggestions, I replaced the ' (single quote) in your first sample with " (double quotes) and I get the message box with the correct variable value and no error, thanks very much @mplungjan

Comment: If there are errors, don’t use the first solution - or check I put the quotes correctly by looking at view source to see if there is one missing